# When do I have to correct for multiple comparison when computing different mutiple regression models?

Tags: regression, p-value, multiple-comparisons, adjustment

I' ve got a problem with my thesis. I use a set of 3 bloodbiomarkers plus age as a covariate to predict Marker of Functional Connectivity on the one hand and Structural Connectivity on the other hand. For Functional connectivity I have one main outcome (global Coherence) and 2 secondary outcomes (2-types of long range coherence) and for Structural Connectivity I have a composite score averaged from three subregions, but beyond that, would like to compute multiple regressions for the three subregions as well. So I was wondering if it would be correct to correct functional connectivity for three comparisons and structural connectivity for four comparisons, or if I may leave the main outcome out without or if I have to compare for even more comparisons? 
I'm kind of stuck to define which hypotheses are from the same family. Would be super happy about some help!